# Android LVL library returning unlicensed during testing

Tags: android, android-lvl

I've been distributing beta APKs to my testers with the LVL checking enabled, and I'm getting many reports of the app behaving as if it is not licensed.

This is not a problem in the current version that is in the Play Store, and the LVL checking code hasn't changed since my last release.

I'm wondering: will the LVL library return 'unlicensed' or behave unpredictably on APKs that have not yet been uploaded to the Android Developer Console? Is it possibly these problems will go away when this update is downloaded from the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pushing my update live, and I've not had any reports of the licensing failing with this code.

As was suggested in [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104649936579980037256/posts/KsempjzPSua) thread, commenting out the versionCode/mVersionCode check in LicenseValidator was likely the reason my beta APK was failing. Hope that helps someone.